# ClamAV continues to say that my definitions are outdated

Tags: antivirus, clamav

I have just updated the definitions for clamav and here is the output:

```
ClamAV update process started at Mon Sep 30 09:22:24 2013
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
WARNING: Local version: 0.97.8 Recommended version: 0.98
DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/support/faq
main.cvd is up to date (version: 55, sigs: 2424225, f-level: 60, builder: neo)
daily.cld is up to date (version: 17915, sigs: 385323, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
bytecode.cvd is up to date (version: 226, sigs: 43, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
```

I have checked if I have any other version of clamav installed, and I don't think I have two instances installed:

```
$ whereis freshclam
freshclam: /usr/bin/freshclam /usr/bin/X11/freshclam /usr/share/man/man1/freshclam.1.gz

$ whereis clamscan
clamscan: /usr/bin/clamscan /usr/bin/X11/clamscan /usr/share/man/man1/clamscan.1.gz

$ ldd which freshclam
which:
ldd: ./which: No such file or directory
freshclam:
ldd: ./freshclam: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?

Comment: Read ClamAV's output again. It says that your definitions are up to date. BTW: `ldd which freshclam` isn't going to do much, you meant `ldd $(which freshclam)`.

Answer (score 4):

ClamAV is not saying your definitions are out of date. On the contrary:

```
main.cvd is up to date (version: 55, sigs: 2424225, f-level: 60, builder: neo)
aily.cld is up to date (version: 17915, sigs: 385323, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
bytecode.cvd is up to date (version: 226, sigs: 43, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
```

It is your *installation* (they mean "installed software version") which is out of date:

```
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
Local version: 0.97.8 Recommended version: 0.98
```

The ClamAV developers apparently think this warrants SHOUTING WARNINGS at you, and use EXCLAMATION MARKS too, which on Linux one wouldn't even see in case of a kernel panic or burning printer port. These warnings are relevant mainly to Windows users (hence their tone, I guess). On Linux you can choose to ignore the warnings and rely on your distro to bring you the latest ClamAV version at the next convenient `apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what zwets said, you can show if there is anything that needs to be updated or removed:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade clamav
```

If you get another angry message about `/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` being full and not wanting to update like I did, just delete some or all of the entries and save:

```
sudo -H gedit /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```